# How to enable two monitors in a notebook?

Tags: multiple-monitors

i have a notebook and this notebook has 2 entries for monitors, one is for HDMI and other is for VGA.

But, when i connect the 2 monitors, 1 monitor in HDMI input and other monitor in VGA input, the system recognize the 2 extra monitors but not enable the 2 monitors for use, just only one.

Anyone can help me?

I tried to configure the xinerama in nvidia-settings, but this configuration has break my O.S, i almost needed to format.

Comment: When you go to launcher, Settings, and then under Devices / Displays, do you see two screens there? Please report back.

Comment: Yes! I see. Due to me being in a notebook that has two inputs, one VGA and one HDMI, when I go to settings / displays, I see 3 screens, 1 monitor connected to VGA, 1 connected to HDAMI and another being the built-in notebook. When I select the monitor connected to the HDMI and click enable, the system turns on and off instantly, and still causes a sort of change in the resolution of others, returning to normal only when I disconnect the HDMI monitor.

Comment: I still not solved this problem, some suggestions?